# Can requiresJS slow down a cordova app that is written using the angular framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, cordova, mobile

I am wondering if a large **angular** app (*around 10 megabytes of js, css, and html files*) that has been ported over to **Cordova** will still need **requiresJS** for lazy loading.

The reason I ask is because I thought requiresJS was mainly focused on *saving bandwidth* by *not loading the entire file at once* and only loading the needed modules for the current view…

**But since Cordova is native** it seems like it would perform much better if it was all loaded from the phones flash drive at the same time?

Another question this brought up is does this stop the actual JavaScript from being loaded into memory until the user navigates to that view?

I tried to research the effects of requiresJS in Cordova applications and did not find anything that answered my question… Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why you'd want to use a module loader such as requireJS beyond lazy loading / saving bandwidth: it will help you manage your dependencies and enable you to write better, modular code.

RequireJS will in no way influence the performance of your application negatively - loading speed for fetching .js files locally is negligible anyway.

> Another question this brought up is does this stop the actual JavaScript from being loaded into memory until the user navigates to that view?

Depending on how you build your application, it is indeed possible (and encouraged) to load code on demand, a.k.a. lazy loading. 
With requireJS it could be as simple as calling 'require('some-library')' at any point in your code where you need it.